# Is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{r}=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|\right)^{r}$ for $0<r<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is the (fractional) power rule true for the limit of a sequence $|a_n|$ at $n \to \infty$, that is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{r}=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|\right)^{r}$$ for $0<r<1$ assuming that $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|=0$?

Edit: Let us take any $\epsilon>0$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $$|a_n-0|<\epsilon^{1/r}.$$ By taking both sides to the power of $0<r<1$ we get that $$|a_n-0|^r<\epsilon,$$ which means that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{|a_n|^r}=0.$

Comment: let $|a_n|\rightarrow a$ four cases cases $a\in \{0\},(0,1),\{1\},(1,\infty)$ can you do each of the cases?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, what I need to verify is the first case, $a = 0$. Can you tell me how to start with it?

Comment: Pick $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  for all $n>N$: $0<a_n<\epsilon^{1/r}$... Just add formalisations to the argument

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the statement is true if we assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$? I will try to edit the question by adding a proof.

Comment: Could you please take a look if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct

Comment: @gaghan Yes your way is right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of limit we have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|=0 \iff \forall \varepsilon>0\quad\exists n_0\quad \forall n>n_0\quad|a_n|<\varepsilon$$

then by $\varepsilon_r=\varepsilon^r$

$$\forall \varepsilon_r>0\quad\exists n_0\quad \forall n>n_0\quad|a_n|^r<\varepsilon^r=\varepsilon_r\iff \lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n|^{r}=0$$